# GDI arc with modification

Tags: winforms, gdi

I have problem with GDI. I do it in WinForms. There is what I got:
[image: my picture]

And there is my code:

```
Graphics phantom = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 150);
float startAngle = 180F;
float sweepAngle = 180F;
phantom.DrawArc(blackPen, rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
phantom.Dispose();
```

I want to get something like that:
[image: my picture2]

Really sorry for my paint skills. Is it possible to create such a thing from the arc itself or do I have to do it from an ellipse? I don't know how to go about it. Any tips are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Well, sure, that's constructed from *three* arcs.  Good luck with the math to compute the intersections.

Comment: You have two circles, let's call them lower and upper.  Define the upper circle as a GraphicsPath and pass that to the constructor of a [Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.region.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Region__ctor_System_Drawing_Drawing2D_GraphicsPath_). Now pass that Region to e.Graphics via the [ExcludeClip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.excludeclip?view=netframework-4.8) method.  Now draw the lower circle, which will be missing the top part because of the clipping.

Comment: Next, Reset() the Graphics and define the lower circle in a GraphicsPath.  Use Graphics.Clip() this time, and chase that with drawing the upper circle. It will only be visible where the lower circle clip was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments on the original post:

> You have two circles, let's call them lower and upper. Define the
>   upper circle as a GraphicsPath and pass that to the constructor of a
>   Region. Now pass that Region to e.Graphics via the ExcludeClip method.
>   Now draw the lower circle, which will be missing the top part because
>   of the clipping.  Next, Reset() the Graphics and define the lower
>   circle in a GraphicsPath. Use Graphics.Clip() this time, and chase
>   that with drawing the upper circle. It will only be visible where the
>   lower circle clip was.

Proof of concept:

[image: Arc Thingy]

Code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics phantom = e.Graphics;
    using (Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
    {
        Rectangle upper = new Rectangle(-50, -250, 300, 300);
        GraphicsPath upperGP = new GraphicsPath();
        upperGP.AddEllipse(upper);
        using (Region upperRgn = new Region(upperGP))
        {
            Rectangle lower = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 150);
            GraphicsPath lowerGP = new GraphicsPath();
            lowerGP.AddEllipse(lower);

            float startAngle = 180F;
            float sweepAngle = 180F;

            phantom.ExcludeClip(upperRgn);
            phantom.DrawArc(blackPen, lower, startAngle, sweepAngle);

            phantom.ResetClip();
            phantom.SetClip(lowerGP);
            phantom.DrawEllipse(blackPen, upper);
        }


    }
}
```